# Problems with eliminating duplicates in my query results

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

The Following query will produce twenty rows. I'm trying to eliminate duplicate versions of 'Type and Version' but I keep returning duplicate

```
SELECT DISTINCT
STR(C.CustomerID, 4) AS 'Customer ID',
STR(INV.InvoiceNbr, 3) AS 'Invoice Number',
STR(LINE.FK_StoveNbr, 3) AS 'Stove Number', 
CAST(S.Type + ', ' + S.Version AS CHAR (15)) AS 'Type and Version'
FROM CUSTOMER C, INVOICE INV, INV_LINE_ITEM LINE, STOVE S
WHERE INV.FK_CustomerID = C.CustomerID
AND INV.InvoiceNbr = LINE.FK_InvoiceNbr
AND SerialNumber = LINE.FK_StoveNbr
AND C.StateProvince = 'OR'
ORDER BY 'Type and Version';
```

Anyway, I keep getting multiple version of the Stove Type and Version in my results. I'm not sure that this is right because there are only ten customers in Oregon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your using a straight join, try switching to a left.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    STR(C.CustomerID, 4) AS 'Customer ID',
    STR(INV.InvoiceNbr, 3) AS 'Invoice Number',
    STR(LINE.FK_StoveNbr, 3) AS 'Stove Number', 
    CAST(S.Type + ', ' + S.Version AS CHAR (15)) AS 'Type and Version'
FROM INVOICE INV,
    LEFT JOIN CUSTOMER C on (C.CustomerID = INV.FK_CustomerID)
    LEFT JOIN INV_LINE_ITEM LINE ON (INV.InvoiceNbr = LINE.FK_InvoiceNbr)
    LEFT JOIN STOVE S ON (S.SerialNumber = LINE.FK_StoveNbr)
WHERE C.StateProvince = 'OR'
ORDER BY 'Type and Version';
```

The reason is Straight joins treat all tables as masters. 1=1, Left Joins let you set a priority. So in my example. INVOICE is the main table. All other tables are just used to fill in extra information. They are attached.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Also. your table naming is a little funky. usually stick with all lowercase. Different db servers treat the case sensitivity differently. And ditch the spaces in the as 'Customer ID'. I'm guessing your outputing these rows straight to html. But you should really keep the 'Customer ID' part in the html(or any other display) and keep a 'customer_id' on the programming side.

Comment: Thank you. I was wondering if that was the case. I found some videos on youtube that have done a better job of explaining LEFT JOIN vs. INNER JOIN than the book I've been using. Although, I'm still unclear on I was producing duplicates.